# Instant run does not work with layout-21

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0, android-instant-run

Here is a case that instant run in AS is not working:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    toolbar.setElevation(visible ? getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.elevation_toolbar) : 0);
} else {
    View toolbarShadow = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_shadow);
    toolbarShadow.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

The view in `layout` has the `R.id.toolbar_shadow`. All good.

However if you have a view in `layout-21` which does not contain the `R.id.toolbar_shadow` then when you compile the app to an e.g. `Api 23` device gradle will fail with :

```
Error:(1046, 42) error: cannot find symbol variable toolbar_shadow
```

Any ideas to solve this?

---

**Update**: as requested the layouts:

`res/layout/actionbar.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ... >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        ... />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_shadow"
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

`res/layout-21/actionbar.xml`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            ... />
```

Comment: Can you show the layout file? At least the relevant part.

Comment: It builds correctly though? Not using Instant Run?

Comment: Yes : without instant run is fine. With instant run it fails with the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution added manually the missing id in the resourses:

```
<!--To make Instant Run work if these ids are not in 21+-->
<item name="toolbar_shadow" type="id"/>
```

Comment: This is strange though, possibly file a bug report?